# Where can I read Guthartha Dipika of Madhusudana Saraswati online, in English?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request, resource

I would like to read the Guthartha Dipika, [Madhusudana Saraswati](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhus%C5%ABdana_Sarasvat%C4%AB#Works)'s commentary on the Bhagavad Gita online, in English. Can anyone provide me the relevant link or PDF for it?

Comment: I have that book at home

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar May I xerox it lol?

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Wait, you stalking me here too?

Comment: I saw your question list and that name Gudhartha Dipika struck my mind.

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar Dont lie, I will tell your Mom

Comment: Don't start off here

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71953/discussion-between-surya-kanta-bose-chowdhury-and-arkaprabha-majumdar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English translation of the commentary of madhusudhana Saraswathy by swamy Gambhirananda of Ramakrishna Mutt is available in the net under the site
https://estudantedavedanta.net/Bhagavad_Gita_Gudartha_Dipika%20_Gambhirananda.pdf.

It is an extraordinary commentary even superior to that of SANKARACHARYA in that the entire wisdom of Patanjali and the vedanta is there.

Answer (score 5):

Madhusudana Saraswati's Gudhartha Dipika is not available online in English.  But it is available in print form in English, [here](https://shop.advaitaashrama.org/product/bhagavad-gita/).

Also, it's available online in Sanskrit [here](https://archive.org/details/BhagvataGitaGudarthaDeepikaTikaShriMadhuSudanSaraswati4995Alm22Shlf4DevanagariVedanta), and in Hindi [here](https://archive.org/details/BhagavadGita-MadhusudanSaraswati).